# Override method (onModelCreating) - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, overriding

I assume that's a basic question but I would appreciate any help.

The issue that I'm having is that when using override modifier on onModelCreating method it's is giving me ":no usitable method found to override".

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyFirstModel> myFirstModel { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MySecondModel> mySecondModel { get; set; }

    protected override void onModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Comment: typo, `onModelCreating` should be `OnModelCreating`

Comment: Typo... Camel casing instead of Pascal in OnModelCreating...